# Export one of Webpack entry points as a library

Tags: webpack, commonjs, webpack-2

I have Webpack configuration for transpiled app:

```
entry: {
    'polyfill': './app/polyfill.js',
    'lib': './app/lib.js',
    'main': './app/main.js'
},
output: {
    path: './bundles',
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
},
...
```

I would like to have `polyfill` and `main` to be loaded from `<script>` tag in browser, and `lib` to be exported as CommonJS library.

`lib` is used by Node backend but contains some of `app` modules, so it is built alongside with other entry points). The application is being transpiled, so it is not possible to just `require` modules from `./app` in Node.

What are the options here? Is using separate Webpack configs and separate Webpack runs the only one?

Comment: You might want to look into externals: https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html

Comment: @Shard Externals are for loading external libraries, not for publishing them, aren't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is better to separate the `lib` from `app`s webpack config. Since the `lib` could be used by both of the modules (front-end, and backend), it could be a library which can be used at both ends.

To create a library with webpack, you can use with the config below,

```
 entry: { lib: './app/lib' },
 output: {
    path: __dirname + '/lib', // path to output
    filename: outputFile, // library file name
    library: libraryName, // library name
    libraryTarget: 'umd', // the umd format
    umdNamedDefine: true // setting this to true will name the AMD module
  },
```

This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41735405/744534) in detail.

Comment: I was hoping I could make it in a single Webpack pass. Too bad that there's no obvious way to do that.

Comment: Since you want to use the `lib` entry as a library, it has to be in the separate webpack config, so that you can get an `output` of library.