# How to create angular2 library which could be supported by all script loaders

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs, umd

How can I create a javascript file that contains an Angular 2 module that can be used by other applications, but is loaded at runtime directly from a centralized server and is NOT bundled into a specific application's code?

Think of this as a CDN for an Angular 2 library. The requirement is that the consumers of this library will include a single script on their page.

It is a requirement to implement it this way, so I am not interested in any answers that suggest bundling the library into the individual application's output files. The library script must be loaded directly from the library's server at runtime.

- The centralized web app is called CustomAuth
- CustomAuth has a single Angular 2 module called `CustomAuthModule`
- CustomAuthModule exposes several services and components that can be used by external Angular 2 applications.

Here is the desired workflow (from a high level).

- A developer wants to use CustomAuth in their Angular2 application called BookLibrary.
- On the developer's index page, they add a script include that points to `http://server-url/CustomAuth/script`. The consumer should not be required to know anything about module loaders like systemjs or webpack.
- In their angular2 code, they import stuff from the CustomAuth module (services, components, etc...).
- When they compile their application using the angular-cli, it will not include the CustomAuth code, but will instead assume that it will be loaded on the fly at runtime.

I've done a lot of research on this, and I'm not having any luck figuring it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you can create polyfil js for your module, like in plunker example we include angular 2 polyfil http://embed.plnkr.co/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU/. this way it will allow user to import js file which user can import in thier index.html and use its module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with `ES6` + `Angular2` + `Webpack`.

Before going into that, Let me explain what is `umd` module system.

> The UMD pattern typically attempts to offer compatibility with the
>   most popular script loaders of the day (e.g RequireJS amongst others)

As quoted above, `UMD` is a pattern where the libraries created with this pattern would support all the modules/script loaders like `requirejs`, `webpack`, `browserify`, `systemjs` etc. I.e the libraries which followed the UMD pattern would be recognized by all the major module systems (`AMD`, `CommonJS`, `ES6` and `Vanilla JS`).

**This is the way that all the libraries in the CDN works.**

Now, even you have to follow the same i.e `UMD` pattern. Since your library is on `angular2`, i would suggest you to go with `ES6`, `Angular2` and `Webpack`.

You have to set these configs to get the library in the UMD format, so that it could be used by any script loaders.

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/lib', // path to output
    filename: outputFile, // library file name
    library: libraryName, // library name
    libraryTarget: 'umd', // the umd format
    umdNamedDefine: true // setting this to true will name the AMD module
  },
```

Once your webpack output bundle is ready (umd module), then any user can inject your library into the index page and start using your angular2 components regardless of script loaders/ modules systems they use.

There is a nice example [here](https://github.com/krasimir/webpack-library-starter) and he explained this [here](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-library-starter-using-webpack-es6)

**Q: How would a consumer of our library include this umd bundle in their Angular 2 application?**

**Ans:** Since your library is going to be a UMD module, user can include the library based on the script loader/module system they are using with their application.

For example. 
Vanilla JS:

```
    <script src="http://example.com/your_lib.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Your_Lib will be available and will attach itself
        // to the global scope.
        var html = Your_Lib.render();
    </script>
```

RequireJS (AMD):

```
    <script src="http://example.com/require.js"></script>
    <script> requirejs config goes here </script>
    <script>
        define(['your_lib', function(Your_Lib) {
             var html = Your_Lib.render();
        }])
    </script>
```

SystemJS (CommonJS):

```
var map = {
            '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
             ....
            'your_lib': 'example.com/your_lib.js'
        };
        var config = {
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
            map: map,
            packages: packages
        };
        System.config(config);
```

Then you can import your library as usual.

Webpack:

In Index.html

In webpack.config.js

```
{
    externals: {
        // require("your_lib") is external and available
        //  on the global var Your_Lib
        "your_lib": "Your_Lib"
    }
}
```

And your library would be available as `Your_Lib` in the global scope.

Comment: How would a consumer of our library include this umd bundle in their Angular 2 application?

Comment: @TwitchBronBron Updated the answer

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran Nice. Will this work with angular-cli?

Comment: I did try with angular-cli. You could try it and let me know.

Comment: Sounds like this is the best solution available. Thanks.